# A problem given to high school students

Tags: recreational-mathematics, problem-solving, exponentiation

My advisor saw this problem in his son's high school textbook,

$$x^{x^{20}}=2^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}$$

How do we solve this? Note that the methods used should be something a high schooler would know.

Comment: Well, I suggest assuming that $x$ has the form $2^a$ and taking $\log_2$ of both sides.

Comment: To stress:  While this has an "analytic" solution in terms of the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) I would not expect a high school student to do it that way.  Instead, I would start from the premise that the answer has to be reasonable simple and search for it along the lines I sketched above.  You will probably also want to assume that $a=2^b$ for some sensible $b$.

Comment: The left handside is increasing, so the solution is unique and we can try to guess it

Comment: And the guessing could be done by what @lulu says, we get something like $s+20 \cdot 2^s = -\frac{1}{2}$, and $s=-3$ looks like working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just putting form to the answer given in the comments.
First, assume $x=2^a$ for some $a \in \mathbb{R}$. Then:

$$x^{x^{20}}=2^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}} \implies {2^a}^{{2^a}^{20}}=2^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}} $$
$$ {2^a}^{{2^a}^{20}}=2^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}} \implies {{a2^a}^{20}}={\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}$$

Now suppose $a = 2^b$ for some $b \in \mathbb{R}$:

$${{a2^a}^{20}}={\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}} \implies 2^b{2^{2^b20}}=2^{-\frac{1}{2}}$$
$$ 2^b{2^{2^b20}}=2^{-\frac{1}{2}} \implies 2^{2^b20+b}=2^{-\frac{1}{2}}$$
$$ 2^{2^b20+b}=2^{-\frac{1}{2}} \implies 2^b20+b=-\frac{1}{2}$$

But the solution for $2^b20+b=-\frac{1}{2}$, by guessing, is $b=-3$. Therefore:
$$ b=-3 \implies a= 2^{-3}$$
$$ a=2^{-3} \implies x=2^{2^{-3}}$$
$$ x=2^{2^{-3}} \implies x=\sqrt[8]{2}$$